# Zend Studio shows: Drupal's DatabaseStatementBase does not define DatabaseStatementInterface.rowCount()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, zend-studio

My eclipse(Zend Studio 12) keeps showing an error in the source code of Drupal's database API that the class `DatabaseStatementBase` implements the interface `DatabaseStatementInterface`, but does not implement the abstract method `DatabaseStatementInterface.rowCount()`.

I am talking about Line#2137 of:  **/includes/database/database.inc**

I was wondering if this is a bug in Drupal or left out intentionally for some design reasons?
Or some problem in my Zend Studio setup?

And how it is possible that `DatabaseStatementBase` is not defined as an abstract class while it is not implementing this abstract method `DatabaseStatementInterface.rowCount()`, and still no fatal errors raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, `DatabaseStatementBase` simply doesn't need to implement `rowCount`.

It extends [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), which does:

[`PDOStatement::rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: I see! So, can we call that a bug in Zend Studio?
Or is it just something wrong with my Zend studio settings?

Comment: May be I should have asked the question differently and tagged this as a zend studio related thing?

Comment: This answer is good, but I updated my question to be more informative. It would be great if the answer also could be updated accordingly.

Comment: The question looks the same to me, what more information were you hoping I can give you? I couldn't tell you if this is a bug with Zend or its configuration (I use PHPStorm which is smart enough to resolve the dependency correctly). The rest of the question is already answered by the fact that `rowCount` _is_ implemented by `DatabaseStatementBase`, albeit indirectly

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question because your answer made me realize that this error I saw is more of an IDE related thing than anything to do with Drupal. My original question was just assuming that the error is a real problem in Drupal and never mentioned anything about the IDE I used. I hope some Zend studio user will show up and add some info.